# Is there an explicit function mapping $2^n+2^m$ to $(n,m)$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functions

We know that the number $2^n+2^m$ is unique for $n,m\in\mathbb{N}$. Is there any explicit way of writing a function $\sigma:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}^2$ such that
$$
\sigma(2^n+2^m)=(n,m),
$$
for all $n,m\in\mathbb{N}$?

**Remark (edit):** Here, $(n,m)$ is to be interpreted as the unordered pair $\{n,m\}$, since I'm only interested in the pair. More specifically, I want to find functions $\sigma,f$ and $g$ such that
$$
\sigma(k)=(g(k),f(k)),
$$
where $k=2^{g(k)}+2^{f(k)}$, $\forall k \in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Such a function can't be well defined, otherwise you would have $\sigma(2^n+2^m) = (n,m)=(m,n)$. But in $\mathbb{N}^2$, you don't identify  $(n,m)$ and $(m,n)$... The image of $\sigma$ should be the set of parts of $\mathbb{N}$ with two elements.

Comment: You're right! I'm more interested in the unordered pair. How may I change my question to be more accurate w.r.t. this?

Comment: You can write $\sigma(2^n + 2^m) = (n,m) \text{ or } (m,n)$ maybe.

Comment: You could write $\sigma(2^n+2^m)=\{n,m\}$. But I'm not sure I understand what your goal is. What you have there is already an eminently explicit and understandable definition of your function -- you may just need to specify explicitly what $\sigma$ does to numbers _not_ of the form $2^n+2^m$. Unless you have _extremely specific and concrete_ requirements to meet, any attempt to make it look "more symbolic" will just succeed in making the definition _harder to understand_. For which purpose would you want that?

Comment: I want a way of recovering the unique integers pair via an explicitly constructible bijection. Please check the edit I made

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What do you think of 
$$\forall k \in \mathbb{N}, \quad \sigma(k)=\left( \lfloor \log_2(k) \rfloor, \lfloor \log_2 \left( k-2^{\lfloor \log_2(k) \rfloor} \right)\rfloor  \right)$$

This is well defined except when $k$ is a power of $2$.

In the other case where $k=2^p$, choose $\sigma(k)=(p-1,p-1)$.

Comment: (+1) Looks like you had the idea first. It's hacky but it works.

Comment: I was a bit confused about the $\lfloor \log_2(k) \rfloor$ choice, but I now understand that this actually picks the highest power between $n$ and $m$, thus the problem with $k=2^p$. Thank you!

Comment: @samwolfe you got it ;)

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to *define* your functions, and you're writing for an audience of human readers, I would strongly recommend writing simply:

> Define the functions $f$ and $g$ such that for all $a\le b$ it holds that
> $$f(2^a+2^b)=a \qquad g(2^a+2^b)=b $$
> and for any number $n$ that is *not* of the form $2^a+2^b$, we have $f(n)=g(n)=0$.
>
> These conditions obviously define $f$ and $g$ uniquely.

This is much easier to understand, and will give the reader a much clearer intuition about what on earth you're doing, than to try to avoid using English words. (Deliberately attempting to avoid English words in definition almost leads to bad mathematical exposition).

If you're writing **not** for a human audience, then what you should write depends crucially on what the non-human audience will understand.

In particular, if you're trying to *program a computer* to implement appropriate $f$ and $g$ for you, you should not be looking for algebraic expressions at all. Rather, exploit the fact that there are operations that work for this *built right into modern CPUs*. On x86/x64 processors they're implemented by the `BSF` and `BSR` instructions. Some programming languages expose them fairly directly, such as `Long.numberOfLeadingZeros(n)` and `Long.numberOfTrailingZeros(n)` in Java -- you need just a bit of trivial arithmetic to convert the result of the former of these to the representation you want.

Answer (score 3):

We have to relax your requirement a bit due to the comment by TheSilverDoe. So we require that for all $\boldsymbol{m \ge n \ge 0}$, $\sigma(2^m + 2^n) = (m, n)$.
Then this is possible. First define
$$
\tau(x) := \lceil \log_2(x) \rceil - 1,
$$
for example, $\tau(2) = 0$, $\tau(3) = \tau(4) = 1$, $\tau(5) = 2$, etc.
Then, define
$$
\sigma(x) := \Big(\tau(x), \tau \left( 1 + x - 2^{\tau(x)} \right) \Big).
$$

**How it works:**

- $\tau(x)$ is the exponent in the largest power of $2$ smaller than $x$; that is, if $2^k < x \le 2^{k+1}$, then $\tau(x) = k$.
- For any $m \ge n \ge 0$, we know that $2^m < 2^m + 2^n \le 2^{m+1}$. Therefore, $\tau(2^m + 2^n) = m$.
- So for $x = 2^m + 2^n$, we get $\tau(x) = m$. Then, $1 + x - 2^{\tau(x)} = 1 + (2^m + 2^n) - 2^n = 2^m + 1$, and the largest power of $2$ smaller than $2^m + 1$ is $2^m$. Thus,
  $$\tau(1 + x - 2^{\tau(x)}) = n,$$
  so
  $$
  \sigma(x) = (m,n).
  $$

**Remark:**
It seems likely that there will be no way to get a function $\sigma$ that does not use floor functions or similar tricks. Some evidence for this is that there is no function on real numbers that satisfies $\sigma(2^x + 2^y) = (x,y)$.

Comment: Yes, I understood my question was initially not so well posed. Thanks for the edit and the explanation, helped me to better understand TheSilverDoe's answer.